# Do pitch accent dictionaries exist for dialects other than Tokyo/Kantō dialect?

Tags: discussion

I know there are pitch accent dictionaries for Kantō/Tokyo/Standard Japanese, at least monolingual Japanese ones, such as NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典.

I wonder if these exist or have ever been published for other dialects? I expect a Kansai one would be the most likely both due to the region's prominence and the very different pitch accent of Kansai-ben.

So are there any pitch accent dictionaries for Kansai or any other Japanese dialect?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this limited to physical books or can it include online resources? Does it have to be published by a credible source?

Comment: @dungarian: I was thinking about physical books. Mainly because I expected such things to be scholarly works published before mainstream Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Samuel E. Martin's *The Japanese Language Through Time* (Yale University Press, 1987) contains a lot of accentual data from various dialects. It is presented in a dense code, but learning, say, a prototypical Kyoto and a prototypical Kagoshima stress from it is easy.